# Ordinary Traveller: How to use/access Timatic?

Tags: visas, air-travel, online-resources, international-travel, timatic

I have read that Timatic is widely used by many Airlines to check what document requirements passengers have to fulfil to board international flights.

The **[Demo link](http://timatic.iata.nl/demo.php)** on Timatic web is broken but I remember having seen it working before but I was not able to understand any of the information it provided.

Can a passenger themselves go through a Timatic request somewhere on web (for free) to see those requirements beforehand?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Timatic is a paid service that airlines use. They offer a free trial, however the service is mostly meant for airlines and similar companies.

[Timatic search for United Airlines](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) is a good search, based on the Timatic database.

Comment: @ugoren Except that's the IATA Travel Centre, based on but not identical with Timatic. The travel centre sometimes has outdated info compared with Timatic

Answer (score 14):

They seem to have a consumer portal:

http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

2023, reverified link, the captcha isn't so annoying anymore.

Comment: Thanks! That is a good find. This is a good option it asks for quite some details before producing a result

Answer (score 10):

And there are airline sites such as https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC
which supposedly use TIMATIC

also, There are some third-party visa agency sites such as https://www.travisa.com/

Answer (score 7):

Another free gateway can be found at https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/ this has the best interface I've seen in this field, allows adding connecting flights, visas, residence permits...

Comment: Worth noting that Traveldoc is another database functionally equivalent to Timatic. It usually has the same content, but sometimes it is formulated differently (and there are probably a few cases where the info is actually different).

Answer (score 7):

> Can a passenger him/herself go through a Timatic request somewhere on web (for free) to see those requirements beforehand?

The best free frontend that works the best for me is the one from [Copa Airlines](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/timatic/)

Contrary to other frontends like Emirates' which limits a lot what data you can enter (like you can't use it if you have anything other than a passport), the Copa Airlines one is a verbatim [Timatic Web2](https://www.timaticweb2.com/) module from IATA and allows you to enter the full query, including transit points.

If you are willing to pay, the other way is to use [ExpertFlyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/)

Comment: I actually like that of Emirates because, while it’s more limited, it only needs very little info. Granted, there are cases it can’t handle, but for 90%+ of queries it’s a lot faster than most other options.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous third party websites that source data from TIMATIC. You won't be able to find free access to TIMATIC readily because it's a premium paid service normally bought by institutions such as airlines.

Skyteam:
https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/

Vistara TIMATIC:
https://www.airvistara.com/in/en/travel-information/vistara-experience/on-ground/visa-requirements/visa-timatic

IATA Travel Centre:
https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/CR-Costa-Rica-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

The last two use the TIMATIC system, whereas the first uses it's own data, but is much more passenger orientated.

Answer (score -1):

the demo link on Timatic web is broken, as you have noticed. However, there are some other ways to access Timatic for free on the web. One option is to use the United Airlines website, which has a Timatic tool that you can use without flying on United Airlines or a Star Alliance airline. Another option is to use the Star Alliance website, which also has a Timatic tool that you can use for free.

To use these tools, you just need to enter your travel details, such as your nationality, destination, transit points, and travel documents. The tool will then show you the passport, visa, and health requirements for your trip, as well as any travel restrictions or warnings. The information is easy to understand and updated regularly.

Comment: That seems to just repeat what other answers already state. Please edit to add new information.