# 6 month passport validity rule for permanent residents in Singapore

Tags: indian-citizens, singapore

I am travelling to Singapore with my child  (both are Permanent residents of Singapore , Indian Nationality )  whose passport is due to expire in March 2018. I am travelling by air India.

I know that Singapore imposes the 6 month passport validity rule for visitors. But I am not sure about how this rule is applicable for permanent residents.

Will Air India let my child board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find out which documents are required, you can run a [Timatic search](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/ordinary-traveller-how-to-use-timatic). Using your [child's information](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&AC=SG&AV=Singapore&DC=SG&DV=Singapore&h=6eccea819931c1d0148725bf0e8129cdf582a1):

> Document Validity:
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of Singapore must be **valid on arrival**.

Since your child is a resident of Singapore, they do not require 6 months validity on their passport. Timatic is the system which airlines use to check document validity, so you are unlikely to face problems with Air India.