# Transit Visa requirement at London Gatwick airport

Tags: visas, uk, transit

This is regarding Transit Visa requirement at London Gatwick airport. I am an Indian passport holder and I have Valid Residence permit (Please refer to image below) which is issued by Iceland which comes under European Economic Area (EEA). I am flying from Iceland to India (Via: Gatwick and Dubai) in the same airport and terminal with 3 hours layover.

As per the GOV.UK site info, The following points stats that as below:

**A common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland** or
**a uniform format category D visa for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland**

As per my understanding, I do not need any Transit Visa at the airport. Can you please conform is my understanding is correct or wrong?

[image]

Thank you,
Sivakrishna.

Comment: This is not UK specific and rather unintuitively has been answered at [Ordinary Traveller: How to use Timatic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89094/4188). However, when asking questions I hate to just receive a close vote instead of help, so I filled out the form for you and you need a visa. Thank Brexit. Here are the results: https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/?S=1|KEF|LGW|2022-03-29&S=2|LGW|DXB|2022-03-01&S=3|DXB|DEL|2022-03-01&D=1|IND|IND|2023-03-01&D=6|ISL|IND|2023-03-01&results=true and you can press the back button on that screen to get back to the form and verify I entered you correctly

Comment: @chx the Skyteam page you linked states that visa is not required for  holders of "Valid category D visa or common format residence permit issued by a European Economic Area member state or Switzerland."

And what does Brexit have to do with any of this?

Comment: @MEEGO and CHX, thank you so much. Skyteam page shows transit is not required if you have boarding on the same day in the same airport.