# Do I need to apply for a visa for transiting on a single ticket?

Tags: transit, indonesian-citizens

If I have a single ticket from Hong Kong to Indonesia that includes a transit stop in Malaysia or Singapore, do I need to apply for a transit visa in either of those countries if I hold an Indonesian passport?

Is there a tool I can use to find a generic answer to similar questions about transit?

Comment: "Malaysia" and "Singapore" are different countries. How can the traveler have a single transit in two locations?

Comment: It says Malaysia/Singapore. Malaysia or Singapore is what the OP meant.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it could be a round-trip ticket with the layover for the outward journey in one place and the inward layover in another place

Comment: Indeed, it could be either. The wording is unclear.

Comment: sorry, we did not buy the ticket yet, the availability of transit are these two countries

Answer (score 3):

For this instance, you don't need transit visa, as Malaysia and Singapore has 'Sterile Transit'. It means, you can get to the connecting flight without going to passport control.

In general, you can look into [TIMATIC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/ordinary-traveller-how-to-use-timatic), which is a system used by airlines to check the document requirements.

Comment: The IATA site can also be used https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: Actually the link in the answer is to Traveldoc, which is a system different from Timatic (but which provided the same service).