# Traveling to Sri Lanka with a French Refugee Travel Document

Tags: paperwork, refugees, eta, sri-lanka

I have a French Travel document for refugee and I wanted to know if I can travel to Sri Lanka for vacation with it.

I know I have to apply for ETA online before but I wanted to know first if I can or not! Thank you so much

Comment: Just to be sure, you are not from Sri Lanka, right?

Comment: @jcaron nooo I’m not from Sri Lanka

Answer (score 1):

[TIMATIC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/ordinary-traveller-how-to-use-access-timatic) states :

> > Sri Lanka - Destination Passport
>
> Passport required. Passport Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a travel document issued to refugees and stateless
> persons and a Residence Permit or Re-entry Permit issued by their
> country of residence.
>
> > Sri Lanka - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required. Visa Issuance
>
> Electronic Travel Authorization (ETA) can be obtained before departure
> at [www.eta.gov.lk](http://www.eta.gov.lk) .

Comment: @Iman Note that Timatic's report indicates that in addition to the French Refugee Travel Document that you already have, you'll need to show a Residence Permit or Re-entry Permit issued by France. Remember too that you'll need to show the airline that you are admissible to any country you'll enter during transit between France and Sri Lanka, in both directions.

Comment: @Iman See the above for the transit part, but once recognized as a refugee you are automatically given a 10 years *titre de séjour*, so presenting a residence permit should not be a roadblock

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica thank you so much

Comment: @NicolasFormichella yess exactly i have it! thank you so much !